# iPad3 - Saving a picture taken on camera to the documents folder of an app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, camera, uiimage, jpeg

From a photo taken by the camera on an iPad 3, I need to save to the documents folder of an app and give the image it's own filename. I can see some mentions of using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to do this but can't see this function anywhere in MonoTouch or example anywhere and not sure if this is the only way. I can save it fine to the PhotosAlbum but want to be able to give the image a name and save locally to the app and not be visible from the main album.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MonoTouch `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` maps to `UIImage.AsJPEG` and will return you an `NSData` that can be saved (using `Save`) anywhere you want.

Have a look at Craig's [blog](http://conceptdev.blogspot.ca/2009/10/monotouch-screen-capture-in-c-code.html) and replace `AsPNG` with `AsJPEG` and you should have it working in no time.

Comment: That's perfect, have got it working from this now. Many thanks